# Lav mic signal produces a periodic ticking sound. Anny ideas?

Tags: lavalier, problems, recording, post-production

I'm wondering what could be the cause of a ticking sound at a regular interval in speech recordings recorded with a sennheiser ew100 and sanken Lav mic through a Wendt mixer on a camera. Th ticking only appears when the person is speaking ( or at least it's only audible when the input signal goes up)

I'm thinking this could be a bad input on the camera.
What ideas do you have.

I
Have some ideas of how to fix this in post. Suggestions on this are welcome too.

Thanks.
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Just riffing off the top of my head: Any number of things could cause this, but my guess is RF or EM interference. A lot depends on what the ticks sound like: Soft thwps, hard hits, just dropouts, etc. Phones and nearby antennae could introduce such sounds, and in Filipe's case, if changing frequency helped, that sounds like RF interference to me. Another possibility is intermodulation, especially if you have an older receiver without a diversity antenna - were you just running one channel of wireless audio, or multiple? Any large metallic objects nearby? Might the EW100's compander be gating all signal unless the subject is speaking, thereby revealing the ticking? Finally, it could be humidity with the lav, but humidity sputtering would probably not be absolutely rhythmic all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had that happening to me this week. I changed the frequency and it stopped, though i really don't know why. (We use Audio limited emitters and receivers)

Answer (score 0):

If the ticks are quite high pitched and regular then the prob could be the antenna connection issues and probably on the transmitter side. Check the shielding is properly connected , maybe resolder to be sure